# Allocating memory in kernel space for struct

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

If I declare a struct A and use that in another struct B. Like struct B { struct A; int len ; } and then I allocate memory for struct B, do I still need to allocate memory for struct A separately ?

What if I use struct *A inside ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `struct A` is embedded into `struct B`:

```
struct B {struct A a; int len;}
```

then you need to allocate memory only for struct B.

If `struct B` has a pointer to `struct A`:

```
struct B {struct A* a; int len;}
```

then you should allocate both structs, and assign pointer to allocated `struct A` to field `a`.